# TensorFlow2 - Model subclassing ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to experiment creating a LeNet-300-100 dense neural network using TensorFlow 2's model sub-classing. The code that I have is as follows:

```
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 20


# Load MNIST dataset-
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255.0

# Convert class vectors/target to binary class matrices or one-hot encoded values-
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

X_train.shape, y_train.shape
# ((60000, 28, 28), (60000, 10))

X_test.shape, y_test.shape
# ((10000, 28, 28), (10000, 10)) 




class LeNet300(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LeNet300, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.dense1 = Dense(units = 300, activation = 'relu')
        self.dense2 = Dense(units = 100, activation = 'relu')
        self.op = Dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.flatten(inputs)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        return self.op(x)




# Instantiate an object using LeNet-300-100 dense model-
model = LeNet300()

# Compile the defined model-
model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=['accuracy']
        )


# Define early stopping callback-
early_stopping_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor = 'val_loss', min_delta = 0.001,
        patience = 3)

# Train defined and compiled model-
history = model.fit(
    x = X_train, y = y_train,
    batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True,
    epochs = num_epochs,
    callbacks = [early_stopping_callback],
    validation_data = (X_test, y_test)
    )
```

On calling "model.fit()", it gives the following error:

> ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (320,))
> should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension
> (received (32, 10)).

What's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Data should be flattened before Dense layer, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65357275/941531).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` doesn't take one-hot encoding to calculate loss. In the documentation, they mention that

> Use this crossentropy loss function when there are two or more label classes. We expect labels to be provided as integers. If you want to provide labels using one-hot representation, please use CategoricalCrossentropy loss. There should be # classes floating point values per feature for y_pred and a single floating point value per feature for y_true.

As a result of this you are getting the error. If you observe the stacktrace the error arises in the loss function,

```
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1569 sparse_categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4941 sparse_categorical_crossentropy
        labels=target, logits=output)
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py:4241 sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2
        labels=labels, logits=logits, name=name)
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py:4156 sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
        logits.get_shape()))

    ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (320,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (32, 10)).
```

I would suggest using `CategoricalCrossentropy`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because input to first Dense layer should be flattened. MNIST data has 28x28 grid/image for every digit. This 28x28 data should be flattened to 784 input numbers.

So just before first `Dense(...)` layer insert `Flatten()` keras layer i.e. do `Flatten()(inputs)`.

See [this doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/flatten/) of Flatten layer for reference.

Comment: I have edited my code as suggested (edited the question to add your edit). The new error I get is: **ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (320,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (32, 10)).**